# app.config - reference to Class?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, reportviewer

I have project in C# in which I have class(name: sql_conClass.cs) that contains connection string builder:

```
 public class myConnection
{

    internal static class DataSource
    {
        private static string _ConnectionString;
        public static string ConnectionString
        {
            get
            {
                if (_ConnectionString == null)
                    _ConnectionString = FunctionToDynamicallyCreateConnectionstring();
                return _ConnectionString;
            }
        }
        private static string FunctionToDynamicallyCreateConnectionstring()
        {

                    SqlConnectionStringBuilder cb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

                    cb.DataSource = Properties.Settings.Default.sql;
                    cb.InitialCatalog = Properties.Settings.Default.database;
                    cb.UserID = Properties.Settings.Default.login;
                    cb.Password = Properties.Settings.Default.pass; 
                    cb.ConnectTimeout = 120;

                     return cb.ToString();

        }
 }
```

Now when I create dinamically DataSource for ReportViewer (I move from Server Explorer from exact server the table that I use for ReportViewer). The project creates it's own connection to this server. So when I create .exe file of my project every one will contain this SqlConnection to this server without option to change it.

My ConnectionBuilder stores in app.config. I wanted to ask whether is  there way to insert reference to this Connectionbuilder into app.config ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every table that is moved dinamically into DataSet creates its own SqlConnection that sets Integrated Security = True e.g. `Data Source=SERVER\SQL;Initial Catalog=database;Integrated Security=True` . I found out that in DataSet.Designer.cs it creates this line of code:

```
private void InitConnection() {
        this._connection = new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        this._connection.ConnectionString = global::tours.Properties.Settings.Default.toursConnectionString1;
    }
```

I just needed to provide right reference to class and change it to this:

```
 private void InitConnection() {
        this._connection = new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        this._connection.ConnectionString = myConnection.DataSource.ConnectionString;
    }
```

Comment: Changes in designer files are a no go, these file get regenerated usually. In fact, app.config has its own section to store connections. Why not use it?